# deleted xcode file not opening

Tags: ios, xcode

I accidentally deleted my xCode project and when I tried to open it back up I was getting this weird message. I am new to xCode and should have used version control first thing. I think it might have something to do with a .app instead of .xcodeproj file type but why would in turn into this in the first place?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzxwNm.png

I would have used these images but my reputation is not high enough.

Comment: did you install new xcode ??

Comment: The error message is very clear. You application version requires higher system version. Either upgrade your mac OS or configure your Xcode project system requirements to suit for your current mac system.

Comment: Are you launching the .app file instead instead of the .xcodeproj file?

Comment: @William Hu ok I will try and configure them. I can't find the macOS 11.1 anywhere can you? the highest I see is 10.13.1 Sierra

Comment: @matloob Hansnain I am running version Version 9.1 (9B55) so yes

Comment: @andlin .xcodeproj has gone missing \:

Comment: You are attempting to launch the compiled iOS app on the Mac. This won’t work. If you have deleted the source code and Xcode project and don’t have a backup then you will need to start again.